# Ionic 3 search with {}

Tags: ionic-framework

Now I can search my item like "123","456".
If I want my item like this items=[{"id":123,"job":"myjob"},{"id":"456,"job":"test"}]
What should I do with my code?

```
onInput(ev : any){
this.initialize();
var val = ev.target.value;
console.log('target',val);
if(val && val.trim() !=''){
this.items = this.items.filter((item)=>{
return(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())>-1);
})
}
}
```

Comment: Try with this may hope it will work if(item && item.id&& item.id.length > 0){}

Comment: I mean I want to search id and job.Umm..if I search my it will show up 123,myjob

Comment: first check item.id with if and please then please check your console result https://jsfiddle.net/qe68dkmw/

Comment: you mean you want to search for both the fields. if the user types 123 or myjob it show display results "123 myjob"

Comment: I had found out how to solve it.THX